# Create / manipulate diagonal matrices in Chapel

Tags: chapel

I have a square matrix `A`

```
use LinearAlgebra;    
proc main() {
  var A = Matrix(
       [4.0, 0.8, 1.1, 0.0, 2.0]
      ,[0.8, 9.0, 1.3, 1.0, 0.0]
      ,[1.1, 1.3, 1.0, 0.5, 1.7]
      ,[0.0, 1.0, 0.5, 4.0, 1.5]
      ,[2.0, 0.0, 1.7, 1.5, 16.0]
      );
}
```

And I want to construct the diagonal matrix `D = 1/sqrt(a_ii)`.  It seems like I have have to extract the diagonal, then operate on each element.  I expect this matrix is be very large and sparse, if that changes the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using the `LinearAlgebra` module in `1.16 (pre-release)`:

```
use LinearAlgebra;

var A = Matrix(
               [4.0, 0.8, 1.1, 0.0, 2.0],
               [0.8, 9.0, 1.3, 1.0, 0.0],
               [1.1, 1.3, 1.0, 0.5, 1.7],
               [0.0, 1.0, 0.5, 4.0, 1.5],
               [2.0, 0.0, 1.7, 1.5, 16.0]
              );

var S = sqrt(1.0/diag(A));

// Type required because of promotion-flatting
// See Linear Algebra documentation for more details..
var B: A.type = diag(S);

writeln(B);
```

Comment: oooohhh, slick!

Comment: Will the conversion step from **`A( 2D, sparse ) -> S( 1D, dense )`**, and the trailing-end flattening-promotion guarantee the final representation of **`B( 2D, diagonal )`** yet remain a sparse representation?

Comment: I mistakenly missed that part of the question. The `LinearAlgebra` module does not yet officially sparse arrays, so there can be on guarantees that its routines will just *work* with sparse arrays. That said, once they do, I'd expect the above code to work as well (where `Matrix` might be something like `sparseMatrix`).

Comment: The type of `S` can be omitted once [#7057](https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/pull/7057) is merged. I'll update this answer once that is live on the `1.16 (pre-release)`.

Comment: So, if I follow your note above, Ben, the declaration below **`var D: [A.domain];`** ought precisely work right-enough for this very reason -- replicating the sparse-**`A`**'s-domain ( so taking here care of having an identical sparse-domain allocation-map for **`D`** ( no values set into `D` so far ) and next, the **`forall{...}`** computes and sets those and only those sparse- **`D`** diagonal elements, that were originally non-zero elements ( there were by-definition none others than non-zero, right? ) on the sparse-**`A`**'s diagonal, correct?

Answer (score 1):

### Did you try this approach?

```
use Math;
var D: [A.domain];
forall      i in D.dim( 1 ) {
        D[i,i] = 1 / Math.sqrt( A[i,i] ); // ought get fused-DIV!0 protection
}
```

<sub>( A.T.M. `<TiO>-IDE` has not so far fully functional the **`LinearAlgebra`** package, so cannot show you the results live, yet hope you would enjoy the way forwards )</sub>

Comment: Although I would prefer the Linear Algebra package because of the new sparse formats coming out.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code that works with a sparse diagonal array in version 1.15 today without linear algebra library support:

```
config const n = 10;   // problem size; override with --n=1000 on command-line

const D = {1..n, 1..n},                        // dense/conceptual matrix size
      Diag: sparse subdomain(D) = genDiag(n);  // sparse diagonal matrix

// iterator that yields indices describing the diagonal
iter genDiag(n) {
  for i in 1..n do
    yield (i,i);
}

// sparse diagonal matrix
var DiagMat: [Diag] real;

// assign sparse matrix elements in parallel
forall ((r,c), elem) in zip(Diag, DiagMat) do
  elem = r + c/10.0;

// print sparse matrix elements serially
for (ind, elem) in zip(Diag, DiagMat) do
  writeln("A[", ind, "] is ", elem);

// dense array
var Dense: [D] real;

// assign from sparse to dense
forall ij in D do
  Dense[ij] = DiagMat[ij];

// print dense array
writeln(Dense);
```

Comment: Note that I think that, ultimately, one would want to create a specialized 'SparseDiagonal' domain map since it's a common case and one that can be represented much more efficiently than a general sparse array.